# Pandas Grouping and Transform Ignoring NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I'm facing an issue with grouping and transforming on non-NA values in my dataframe.

So my dataframe is something like this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | NaN |
| B | 3 |
| B | 7 |
| B | 9 |
| B | NaN |

Final output I want:

| Name | Value | Weight 1 | Weight 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.33 | 0.5 |
| A | 2 | 0.33 | 0.5 |
| A | NaN | 0.33 | NaN |
| B | 3 | 0.25 | 0.33 |
| B | 7 | 0.25 | 0.33 |
| B | 9 | 0.25 | 0.33 |
| B | NaN | 0.25 | NaN |

I know this may sound trivial but I'm not able to get the Weight 2 working perfectly across different grouping categories of column `Name`.

Here's how I get column `Weight 1`:

```
df['Weight 1'] = df.groupby(['Name']).transform(lambda x: 1/len(x))
```

So far I tried following on `Weight 2`, but raises DivisionByZero warning. Output is incorrect.

```
df['Weight 2'] = df.groupby(['Name']).transform(lambda x: 1/np.sum(~np.isnan(x)))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) to count Non-NaN values in each group. Then use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
mapping = (1 / df.groupby('Name')['Value'].count()).squeeze()
df['Weight 2'] = df['Name'].map(mapping).mask(df['Value'].isna())

  Name  Value  Weight 2
0    A    1.0  0.500000
1    A    2.0  0.500000
2    A    NaN       NaN
3    B    3.0  0.333333
4    B    7.0  0.333333
5    B    9.0  0.333333
6    B    NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks mate... your code however is simpler (IMO more to the point)

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly! Nice work with `map` and `mask` not so obvious functions.

Comment: @SaurabhGokhale They are nice handy functions. I have linked to pandas documentation which has an excellent explanation with examples.

Answer (score 3):

`count` ignores nulls when counting, `size` does not:

```
grouper = df.groupby('Name')
(df.assign(Weight1 = 1/grouper.Value.transform('size'), 
          Weight2 = 1/grouper.Value.transform('count'))
   .assign(Weight2 = lambda df: np.where(df.Value.notna(), 
                                        df.Weight2, np.nan))
 
  Name  Value   Weight1   Weight2
0    A    1.0  0.333333  0.500000
1    A    2.0  0.333333  0.500000
2    A    NaN  0.333333       NaN
3    B    3.0  0.250000  0.333333
4    B    7.0  0.250000  0.333333
5    B    9.0  0.250000  0.333333
6    B    NaN  0.250000       NaN
```

Comment: Weight 1 is correct. Weight 2 is not correct because it also assigns 0.33 and 0.5 to rows where `Value` value is NaN